# How to check if Southwest Airlines flight is actually canceled?

Tags: southwest-airlines

In the last few days, Southwest Airlines has cancelled ~60% of its flights. I received a text message from 64553 saying my flight had been cancelled; however, when I checked the Southwest website, it says nothing about the cancellation, showing my reservation.

How can I figure out which is reality?

Comment: It's entirely possible that your _reservation_ still shows on Southwest's reservation system, while the _actual flight_ has been canceled. Why else would Southwest send you such a text? You can check directly with Southwest [here](https://www.southwest.com/air/flight-status/?clk=TRAVEL-DISRUPTION-LP) or ask FlightAware [here](https://flightaware.com).

Comment: As the flight is the day after tomorrow, this unfortunately does not work. And yes, I completely agree that my flight almost certainly is canceled; however, if it's not, I'll need to cancel the replacement flight I got on another airline.